# XE4 iOS app won't deploy to device

Tags: delphi

I have a `Delphi XE4 iOS` app that runs fine in the simulator but not on a device (`iPad`). It appears to deploy OK as I get no errors and the `dSYM` gets copied.

I believe I have the certificate setup OK.

`PA` server is running.

All I get on the device is a large `Firemonkey` image, so it's at least communicating.

I have noticed that in the 'Deployment' section, the `dSYM` file status on the remote device is 'not found', also 'Project Output' is newer. I've redeployed but still shows as newer.

Can't find any logs that help (is there a `PAserver` log?)

Comment: Is this a new failure? Have you ever run a real application on a real device? Does it work if you try a sample application from XCode? I would go and check your Provisioning Profiles from within the XCode GUI.

Comment: I've had a phonegap app running from xcode OK, but nothing from Delphi - this is my first Delphi iOS app.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out there is another problem (SQLite DB is readonly) that was stopping it running or reporting an error. If I don't run any code on create, it loads fine.

Comment: Fixed that and all now OK!